# Entity field type custom query parameter

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to build a `Entity` field type in Symfony 2 and pass a parameter to query builder for filter list of related objects:

```
$formMapper
            ->add('article_subcategories', 'entity',
                    array(
                         'label' => 'Podkategorie',
                         'multiple' => true,
                         'expanded' => true,
                         'read_only' => true,
                         'class' => 'FachowoArticleBundle:ArticleSubcategory',
                         'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er)
                         {
                             return $er
                                     ->createQueryBuilder('sc')
                                      ->where('sc.article_category = :id')
                                      ->orderBy('sc.name', 'ASC')
                                      ->setParameter('id', $id);
                         }
                    ));
```

How can i pass $id to this function inside formMapper ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use PHP 5.3's closures. Most languages with closures do this automatically, but PHP requires that you specify the list explicitly.

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($id)
   {
      return $er
        ->createQueryBuilder('sc')
        ->where('sc.article_category = :id')
        ->orderBy('sc.name', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice way is to use the options array when you create the form, so pass id in the array, then in the form do:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $id = $options['id'];
    $builder
        ->add('foo', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Foo',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($id) {
                return $er->findByBar($id);
            }
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that you cannot just add arbitrary items to a FormType's $options; you need to declare them by overriding the FormType's getDefaultOptions method.